# Joint PDF of two independent normal distributions

Tags: probability, statistics

I had this on my Probability final, and it stumped me. Exam is over and I still got a B, but here's the problem:

Let X1, X2 be distributed as N(0,1) and N(0,9), respectively. Let Y1 = X1-X2, and let Y2 = X2.  Give the joint pdf g(y1,y2) and the marginal distributions. Does this one require transformations?

Comment: What about the joint distribution of $X_1, X_2$? You need that or you have to assume that $X_1, X_2$ are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}$If you assume independence, the marginal distribution of $Y_1$ is easy to find.  And I don't think you need to do anything to find the marginal distribution of $Y_2$ beyond understanding what you've written above.
$$
\var(X_1-X_2) = \var(X_1)+\var(-X_2) = \var(X_1)+(-1)^2\var(X_2) = 1+9,
$$
and it's easy to find $\operatorname{E}(X_1-X_2)$.  The sum of two independent normally distributed random variables is normally distributed, so you get
$$
X_1-X_2\sim N(0,10).
$$
To find the joint PDF, notice that $(Y_1,Y_2)$ is a linear tranformation of $(X_1,X_2)$ and use what you know about Jacobians.